# how can i find the angle of a reflecting line?

Tags: javascript, math

i am trying to make the game [pong](http://www.ponggame.org/) ( my math is really bad and i am working on it) and trying to do the bouncing ball part.

I am trying to calculate the out going(reflecting) angel of the ball after hitting the walls or pedals (the walls are always horizontal and the pedals are always vertical)

Here is an image to demonstrate it better :

[image: reflecting image]

here is what i tried so far:

```
var m  = (y2-y)/(x2-x);
var angle = (Math.atan(-m)*57.2957795);
```

How ever this does not seem to work.

Comment: In each of the cases you have illustrated the magnitude of angleB is the same as the magnitude of angle A. Your code makes little sense since you haven't shown what the variables are supposed to represent.

Comment: the javascript part i did, i was trying to find the slope and then adding a - to it to get the opposite slope and then convert it back to angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the obstacles are always vertical or horizontal, you do not need to do any angle calculations.
If you store the ball's position as (x, y) and it's velocity as (v<sub>x</sub>, v<sub>y</sub>) you can at each frame compute the next position to (x + v<sub>x</sub>, y + v<sub>y</sub>)

To bounce from a horizontal border, just negate v<sub>y</sub>, to bounce from vertical borders negate v<sub>x</sub>.

Comment: The way i have it working right now, is that i need to supply an angle to move into a certain direction. how will i change the y?